# Maps API for Adobe AIR (AS3) on 2017

Tags: actionscript-3, google-maps-api-3

It's Dec 2016. The Adobe Flash and [Google Maps API for Flash](https://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/09/maps-api-for-flash-deprecation.html) has been deprecated, and I have a major project coming up that relies heavily on maps. What should I do to make it work on AIR?

Thinking of: Google Maps JavaScript API + Mobile web view. A little worried about power consumption or ram issues on lower performance smartphones.

Is that my best bet? Or, is there one out there that still works for AIR?

---

*Edit:* Something like [*ArcGIS API for Flex*](https://developers.arcgis.com/flex/) would be great! Although, it seems they just went into retirement phase...

Comment: Can the user who doused me with a -1 shed some light on why they did so? I know some people don't like flash but that's no excuse. Tired of posting as3 related questions and getting a negative rating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may using ANE to solve this kind of problems

a costly Ane (iOS v5.1+ & Android v10+) [com.distriqt.NativeMaps](http://airnativeextensions.com/extension/com.distriqt.NativeMaps)

> The Native Maps allows you to display native iOS Apple maps and
>   Android Google maps with interactivity and overlays in your
>   applications.
>   This allows you to provide high performance mapping applications well
>   integrated with your AIR application. Select between normal, hybrid
>   and satellite map types and control the view setting positions,
>   bounds, zoom and tilt.

a free Ane (Only for IOS) [air-maps-ane](https://github.com/rozdonmobile/air-maps-ane)

> AIR Maps ANE provides the support for using the native mapping
>   component in your Adobe AIR application. It uses Native Extensions to
>   access the maps APIs for that platform and provides an AS3 interface
>   so that it can be used in Flash Mobile applications developed using
>   Adobe AIR.

or create your own ANE.

Answer (score 4):

There's [openscales](http://openscales.org). It's not actively developed anymore, but it is open source.

Answer (score 1):

The Google, in its [Maps API for Flash deprecation announcement](https://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/09/maps-api-for-flash-deprecation.html) states:

> The performance and consistency of *browser JavaScript* implementations
>   has progressed, making the JavaScript Maps API an increasingly
>   suitable alternative.

[*However*](http://www.republicofcode.com/2011/09/04/maps-api-flash-deprecated/),

> While the deprecation of Google Maps API for Flash was a sad
>   announcement to Flash developers (back in September, 2011), it should
>   be mentioned that it is still possible to use the Google [JavaScripts
>   Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/)
>   within Flash projects by loading it as an HTML page, which may just
>   work for *some* projects, even though it cannot be controlled as easy
>   using ActionScript.

The preceding page mentions the [MapQuest AS3
API](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/featured/as3-flex-flash), as an alternative, but unfortunately, it seems to be also [deprecated](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/flash-api/)! So, I think your *best bet*, is the best bet!

Answer (score 1):

[YCanvas](https://github.com/jozefchutka/YCanvas) is also not actively developed but it can make the trick and it's also opensource
I used it in this app : http://volcansdauvergne.com/ few years ago